# Why am I getting NaN on one out of every string of numbers?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, nan

```js
var countsTest = [{"roundId":19,"scores":[{"scoreId":181,"score":2,"holePar":3,"name":"Birdie","color":"#77ACD8"},{"scoreId":182,"score":4,"holePar":3,"name":"Bogie","color":"#FBD59C"},{"scoreId":183,"score":4,"holePar":3,"name":"Bogie","color":"#FBD59C"},{"scoreId":184,"score":2,"holePar":3,"name":"Birdie","color":"#77ACD8"},{"scoreId":185,"score":3,"holePar":3,"name":"Par","color":"#eee"},{"scoreId":186,"score":2,"holePar":3,"name":"Birdie","color":"#77ACD8"},{"scoreId":187,"score":3,"holePar":3,"name":"Par","color":"#eee"},{"scoreId":188,"score":3,"holePar":3,"name":"Par","color":"#eee"},{"scoreId":189,"score":3,"holePar":3,"name":"Par","color":"#eee"}],"roundDate":"2023-03-04T00:00:00.000+01:00","total":26,"barChartArray":[2,4,4,2,3,2,3,3,3],"dateWithoutTimeOfDay":"2023-03-04"}];

const counts = {};

        for (let i = 0; i < countsTest.length; i++) {
          const num = parseInt(countsTest[i]);
          counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
        }

        const oldChart = chart.chart;
        if (oldChart) {
          oldChart.destroy();
        }

        const myChart = new Chart(chart, {
          type: 'bar',
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
              x: {
                stacked: true,
                display: false
              },
              y: {
                stacked: true,
                display: false
              }
            },
            plugins: {
              legend: {
                display: false
              }
            }
          },
          data: {
            labels: ["Score"],
            datasets: [{
              data: [counts[2] || 0],
              backgroundColor: "#77ACD8"
            }
            ,{
              data: [counts[3] || 0]

            },{
              data: [counts[4] || 0],
              backgroundColor: "#FDC26A"
            },{
              data: [counts[5] || 0],
              backgroundColor: "#FCAE37"
            },{
              data: [counts[6] || 0, counts[7] || 0, counts[8] || 0, counts[9] || 0, counts[10] || 0],
              backgroundColor: "#FCAE37"
            }
            ]
          }
        });
        chart.chart = myChart;
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

I'm a complete beginner to JavaScript, I have a springboot project for discgolf, and have an accordion for each course, which opens to all rounds played for a user. I'm creating n horizontal barcharts and passing a round to JavaScript to render the chart using chart js.

html (round coming from a th:each)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <canvas th:data-counts="${round}"></canvas>
</div>
```

my chart JavaScript

```
const charts = document.querySelectorAll('[data-counts]');
      charts.forEach(chart => {
        const countsTest = chart.getAttribute('data-counts').split(',');

        const counts = {};

        for (let i = 0; i < countsTest.length; i++) {
          const num = parseInt(countsTest[i]);
          counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
        }


        console.log(countsTest); // Log the countsTest array
        console.log(counts); // Log the counts object

        const oldChart = chart.chart;
        if (oldChart) {
          oldChart.destroy();
        }

        const myChart = new Chart(chart, {
          type: 'bar',
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
              x: {
                stacked: true,
                display: false
              },
              y: {
                stacked: true,
                display: false
              }
            },
            plugins: {
              legend: {
                display: false
              }
            }
          },
          data: {
            labels: ["Score"],
            datasets: [{
              data: [counts[2] || 0],
              backgroundColor: "#77ACD8"
            }
            ,{
              data: [counts[3] || 0]

            },{
              data: [counts[4] || 0],
              backgroundColor: "#FDC26A"
            },{
              data: [counts[5] || 0],
              backgroundColor: "#FCAE37"
            },{
              data: [counts[6] || 0, counts[7] || 0, counts[8] || 0, counts[9] || 0, counts[10] || 0],
              backgroundColor: "#FCAE37"
            }
            ]
          }
        });
        chart.chart = myChart;
      });
```

Round data in the console

```
['Round{roundId=19', ' course=Course{id=1', " name='Legende'", ' holes=[Hole{holeId=37', ' number=1', ' par=3}', ' Hole{holeId=38', ' number=2', ' par=3}', ' Hole{holeId=39', ' number=3', ' par=3}', ' Hole{holeId=40', ' number=4', ' par=3}', ' Hole{holeId=41', ' number=5', ' par=3}', ' Hole{holeId=42', ' number=6', ' par=3}', ' Hole{holeId=43', ' number=7', ' par=3}', ' Hole{holeId=44', ' number=8', ' par=3}', ' Hole{holeId=45', ' number=9', ' par=3}]', ' par=27', ' record=-2', ' courseAverage=27.238095238095237}', ' scores=[Score{scoreId=181', ' score=2', ' holePar=3', " name='Birdie'", " color='#77ACD8'}", ' Score{scoreId=182', ' score=4', ' holePar=3', " name='Bogie'", " color='#FBD59C'}", ' Score{scoreId=183', ' score=4', ' holePar=3', " name='Bogie'", " color='#FBD59C'}", ' Score{scoreId=184', ' score=2', ' holePar=3', " name='Birdie'", " color='#77ACD8'}", ' Score{scoreId=185', ' score=3', ' holePar=3', " name='Par'", " color='#eee'}", ' Score{scoreId=186', ' score=2', ' holePar=3', " name='Birdie'", " color='#77ACD8'}", ' Score{scoreId=187', ' score=3', ' holePar=3', " name='Par'", " color='#eee'}", ' Score{scoreId=188', ' score=3', ' holePar=3', " name='Par'", " color='#eee'}", ' Score{scoreId=189', ' score=3', ' holePar=3', " name='Par'", " color='#eee'}]", ' roundDate=2023-03-04 00:00:00.0', ' total=26', ' barChartArray=[2', ' 4', ' 4', ' 2', ' 3', ' 2', ' 3', ' 3', ' 3]}']
```

Honestly I'm not sure how the scores are getting to the barchart but its kind of working but I'm still getting a NaN for one of the scores in each round. The screen shot shows the correct score card but each chart is wrong by one number, it also shows the output in the console. As you can see there are 3: 2s in the scorecard, but on the barchart there is only 2. {2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 2, NaN: 81})

So how do I use the scores object inside a round to create the chart? So use score.score or barChartArray for the numbers, for the label score.name and for the color `score.color`.

[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: not sure what are you trying to do here or what are you trying to convert to number, but if you are getting NaN then your code is trying to parse a value that probably contains numbers and characters as well at a certain point in your loop. You should try debugging. See what this prints inside your loop `console.log(countsTest[i]);` and you might find out whats wrong

Comment: I have honestly done a lot of research. So the score card has scores: 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3. The bar chart should have 2 scored 3 times (so no confusion, looking at the score card for 9 holes played: 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3. Holes: 1, 4 and 6 all scored 2. But in the screen shot if you hover over the blue section which is for 2s, there is only 2 (there should be three 2s in blue. This happens with every chart, also there must be a better way as to how I code the labels and datasets? Birdie 1 under par is blue, grey par and orange 1 over par.

Comment: The most important thing you can do for any question on Stack Overflow is to include code which demonstrates the problem. We don't have access to your environment, so it's up to you to boil your code down to the least amount of data and code required to produce the same result as you are seeing. See the links provided by @mplungjan in the first comment for more guidance. Until you do that, we would be guessing and that helps only you, and this site was made to help everyone.

Comment: Sorry really tried to get the code snippet to work, I put in as much as I could.

Comment: The code needs to be from view-source and you need to include `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>`

Comment: Sorry guys rookie mistake, incorrect json. But thank you. I'll post what I was trying to achieve below.

Comment: @KaydAnderson  no need to apologise for asking a question. Everyone was a rookie once. Keep going forward.

Answer (score 0):

So it was my json, what I ended up doing was passing the full list of rounds to my javascript, then inside the thymeleaf loop I passed the roundId via the th:roundId.

html
inside the thymeleaf loop

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
     <canvas th:roundId="${round.roundId}" th:id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

passing the full list of rounds

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    let rounds = /*[[${roundsJsonNode}]]*/ {};
</script>
```

then in the javascript I get the round by id using the getRoundsById method, and create a bar chart for each round.

```js
function getRoundById(rounds, roundId) {
      return rounds.find((round) => round.roundId === Number(roundId));
    }

    

    const charts = document.querySelectorAll('[roundId]');
      charts.forEach(chart => {
        const getRound = chart.getAttribute('roundId').split(',');
        const roundData = getRoundById(rounds, getRound);

        const scoreCount = roundData.scores.length;
        const scoreData = {};

        for (let i = 0; i < scoreCount; i++) {
          const score = roundData.scores[i];
          if (!scoreData[score.name]) {
            scoreData[score.name] = {
              count: 0,
              color: score.color,
              score: score.score,
            };
          }
          scoreData[score.name].count += 1;
        }

        const datasets = [];
        Object.entries(scoreData).forEach(([name, data]) => {
          datasets.push({
            label: name,
            backgroundColor: data.color,
            data: [data.count],
            score: data.score, // add score value to dataset object
          });
        });

        datasets.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score); // sort datasets by score value

        const myChart = new Chart(chart, {
          type: 'bar',
          options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
              x: {
                stacked: true,
                display: false,
              },
              y: {
                stacked: true,
                display: false,
              },
            },
            plugins: {
              legend: {
                display: false,
              },
            },
          },
          data: {
            labels: [''],
            datasets,
          },
        });
      });
```